# ajax filter json data

Tags: jquery, ajax

At the moment my json output looks like this:

```
Object {results: Array(26)}
results
:
Array(26)
0
:
Object
api_key
:
10565
business_id
:
1
created_at
:
null
date
:
"2017-06-19"
email
:
"n/a"
facebook_business
:
null
gallery_id
:
null
id
:
1
image
:
null
instagram_business
:
null
logo
:
null
name
:
"Odeon Cinema"
times
:
"12:40"
title
:
"Guardians of the Galaxy"
twitter_business
:
null
type
:
"3"
updated_at
:
null
user_id
:
1
```

Each object has a cinema "name" however there are only 3 cinemas.

is it possible to filter the data and output it like this:

Cinema name
 - film times
 - film times

Cinema name
 - film times
 - film times

Cinema name
 - film times
 - film times

My Ajax:

```
function cinema_films(film_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/filmsearch/' + film_value,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var html = '';
            $.each(data.results, function(index, film) {
                console.log(film.name);
                html += film.title +' '+ film.times +' '+ film.name + '<br />';
            });
            $('#films').html(html);
        },
        error: function(data) {

        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }                 
    });
}
```

//edit

```
{"results":[{"id":2,"title":"Guardians of the Galaxy 2","times":"12:00, 15:00, 18:00, 21:00","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Baywatch","times":"13:20, 16:00, 18:40, 21:20","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Pirates of the Caribbean: Salazar's Revenge","times":"11:20, 14:20, 17:20, 19:10, 20:20","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Wonder Woman","times":"11:30, 13:10, 14:30, 16:20, 17:20, 18:00, 19:30, 21:10","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"The Mummy","times":"11:30, 13:00, 13:40, 14:10, 14:40, 15:40, 16:20, 16:50, 18:20, 19:00, 19:40, 20:30, 21:00","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Gifted","times":"12:50, 15:20, 17:50, 20:20","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Diary Of A Wimpy Kid - The Long Haul","times":"11:50, 14:20, 16:40","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Alien - Covenant","times":"11:40, 15:00, 20:50","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"My Cousin Rachel","times":"12:20, 15:00, 17:30, 20:00","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"Churchill","times":"12:20, 14:50, 17:20, 19:50","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":2,"title":"The Shack","times":"12:00, 17:50","business_id":2,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Cineworld Ashton","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":7311},{"id":1,"title":"Guardians of the Galaxy","times":"12:40","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"Guardians of the Galaxy 2","times":"12:40","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"Baywatch","times":"15:40, 18:20, 21:00","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"Pirates of the Caribbean: Salazar's Revenge","times":"11:45, 14:45, 17:45, 20:45","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"Wonder Woman","times":"13:45, 15:15, 17:00, 20:15, 21:15","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"The Mummy","times":"12:30, 14:30, 17:15, 18:30, 20:00","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"My Cousin Rachel","times":"12:00, 12:30, 15:00, 17:30","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":1,"title":"Churchill","times":"12:45, 15:15, 17:45, 20:15","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Cinema","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":10565},{"id":3,"title":"Baywatch","times":"12:50, 15:30, 18:10, 20:50","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"Pirates of the Caribbean: Salazar's Revenge","times":"13:45, 16:45, 19:45","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"Wonder Woman","times":"13:10, 14:00, 16:20, 17:10, 19:30, 20:30","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"The Mummy","times":"12:00, 13:00, 14:45, 15:45, 17:20, 18:20, 19:00, 21:00","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"Gifted","times":"13:45, 18:30, 21:00","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"Diary Of A Wimpy Kid - The Long Haul","times":"14:00, 16:30","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434},{"id":3,"title":"My Cousin Rachel","times":"12:20, 15:00, 18:00, 20:40","business_id":3,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Odeon Rochdale","type":"3","email":"n/a","logo":null,"twitter_business":null,"facebook_business":null,"instagram_business":null,"image":null,"gallery_id":null,"user_id":1,"api_key":9434}]}
```

Comment: have you tried with `JSON.parse(data);` ?

Comment: @NiravJoshi since `dataType: 'json'` is already specified this should be unnecessary. Setting this option means jQuery will automatically create an object from the response already (assuming that the response is in fact valid JSON - if not it will throw an error in the console). Also the OP makes no mention of having a problem reading the object, instead they want to know how to do filtering etc on it. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: @Przemyslaw "Each object has a cinema "name" however there are only 3 cinemas." This appears to bear no relation to the object you've shown in your example. There's only one cinema name in that example, and it's not under a "name" property. Nor are there any film times etc. Can you show the actual JSON that you are referring to here? It's almost certainly possible to do what you want but without seeing the real data structure it's a lot harder to do so.

Comment: @ADyson there is name
:
"Odeon Cinema"
Give me a minute to try and get picture

Comment: try here http://imgur.com/JiT39sc of course sometimes name repeats as cinema has multiple films but there are 3 cinemas

Comment: Ok I see it did, but missed it because of the poor formatting and the list not actually being in JSON notation. And no please not a picture, the actual JSON is what's needed - the output of `JSON.stringify(data);` (or at least a sample of it) would be the thing to include here.

Comment: check my edit please, is that okay? @ADyson

Comment: yes thankyou. Firstly I should ask if it's possible to re-structure the JSON coming from the server? If so, it would be easier if you have something like this: `{ "results" : [ { "name": "Cineworld Ashton", "id": 1, "films": [ { "id": 1, "name": Guardians of the Galaxy 2", "times": ["12:00", "15:00", "18:00", "21:00"], date: "2017-06-19" }, { ///another film } //...etc  ]}, { //...another cinema } //..etc ]}` where the results are already grouped by cinema, and the times are actually an array instead of a comma-separated string.

Comment: well the user is selecting a date which is then matched by a date in films table and then retrieving data from business table that is associated with that film, I don't know if it's possible to do it other way round as you are searching by date not by business

Comment: I tried finding a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628304/laravel-eloquent-group-results-using-another-table

Comment: anything is possible if it's your server code. You'd just have to assemble the JSON however you wish by processing the database data. Different types of search could even return different structures (e.g. by cinema, by day, by time, by film). Depends if you can / are willing to do that. If not, I can answer the question using the structure you have already got.

Comment: It is my server code but I don't know how to do it really but I need to search by date. Please do answer with structure I have at the moment, in future I might figure out how to change it  @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what HTML you want to use, but something like this should give you the general idea. Essentially, it loops through the data, keeps a record of cinema names it has encountered, and adds records to arrays, one for each cinema. Once it's finished, it then loops through all of the arrays and writes out the HTML, starting a new list for each cinema-specific array. This ensures that the data is grouped by cinema.

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  //sort the data into arrays for the different cinemas
  var cinemas = {};

  $.each(data.results, function(index, film) { //here assumed "id" is ID of the cinema, from the JSON sample it looks like this is the case
    if (!cinemas[film.id]) { cinemas[film.id] = { "name": film.name, "films": [] }; } //create new cinema if needed
    cinemas[film.id].films.push(film);
  });

  //loop through each cinema and generate a list of films per-cinema
  var html = '';
  $.each(cinemas, function(prop, cinema) {
    html += "<h4>" + cinema.name + "</h4><ul>";

    $.each(cinema.films, function(index, film)
    {
      html += "<li>" + film.title +'<br/>'+ film.times + '</li>';
    });
    html += "</ul>";
  });

  $('#films').html(html);
},
```

It's bit verbose, and as I mentioned in the comments you can probably do the grouping part more efficiently on the server by using the right database queries and code to create more structured JSON in advance. Obviously you'd still need something to create the related HTML on the client-side by making use of the JSON.